# Speed up string search algorithm

Tags: c#, string, performance, dictionary

I am using this simple algorithm for searching some text in document and taging on which page I found it

```
for (int i = 1; i <= a.PageCount; i++)
{
    Buf.Append(a.Pages[i].Text);
    String contain = Buf.ToString();
    if (contain != "")
    {
        // Inside is dictionary of keys and value contain page where I found it
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> pair in inside)
        {
              if (contain.Contains(pair.Key))
                  inside[pair.Key].Add((i).ToString());
        }
    }

    Buf.Clear();
 }
```

I have no problem with it, but when I search in 700 pages document and I am looking for over 500 keys, its very slow, took about 1-2 minutes to pass, is there any way how to speed it up? I am using c#

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of document is a?  Could you start with determining what keys are actually in the whole file and then just search for those on a page by page basis?

Comment: Its pdf document, but it doesnt matter on file format, its come catalog of product and some pages contain table with product types - i need to create index of all keys - where they are - on which pages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few points:

- Get rid of `Buf`; just assign `a.Pages[i].Text` directly to `contain`:
- `inside[pair.Key]` wastes time looking up the value associated with that key; the time is wasted because you have a much cheaper reference to that object in `pair.Value`.
- if you have a list of integer values, why are you storing them as strings?

Sample code:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= a.PageCount; i++)
{
    String contain = a.Pages[i].Text
    if (contain != "")
    {
        // Inside is dictionary of keys and value contain page where I found it
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<int>> pair in inside)
        {
            if (contain.Contains(pair.Key))
                pair.Value.Add(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, make sure `Pages` does in fact use a one-based index.  Collections are more commonly zero-indexed.

**EDIT** since `Pages` is a dictionary:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Page> kvp in a.Pages)
{
    string contain = kvp.Value.Text;
    if (contain == "")
        continue;
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<int>> pair in inside)
        if (contain.Contains(pair.Key))
            pair.Value.Add(kvp.Key);
}
```

How many times did you time the first code sample?  The time could vary depending on many external factors; the fact that a single run of one approach is faster or slower than a single run of another doesn't really tell you much, especially since the suggestions I made probably don't address the bulk of the problem.

As someone else pointed out, the main problem is that you're calling `contain.Contains(pair.Key)` 350,000 times; that's probably your bottleneck.  You can profile the method to find out if that is true.  If it *is* true, then something like the Rabin Karp algorithm as suggested by Miserable Variable is probably your best bet.

Comment: I tried it, but it took longer than before, I have no idea why. Pages are Dictionary type and yes, its pages from pdfLibNet, and they are indexed starting by 1

Comment: @MartinCh if it is a dictionary type then you could use "foreach (KeyValuePair<...` there, too, though the benefit will be smaller -- you're saving 700 lookups rather than 350K.

Comment: thanks, after I run code analysis, I found out, that Pages[].Text took about 89% of processing time, so there is main problem

Comment: @MartinCh An excellent confirmation of the advice to profile your code before attempting to improve its performance!

Answer (score 3):

[[

EDIT: The following is irrelevant, since you are clearing Buf at the end of loop (though note that you don't really need buf, `string pageText = a.Pages[i].Text` is all you need)

What is `Buf`? You have

```
Buf.Append(a.Pages[i].Text);
```

Does that not force the `Contains` to look through increasingly large size strings? I am surprised you are not running out of memory with 700 pages.

]]

There are more efficient ways to see if `any of a set of strings` appears in another `string`. For example, you could prepare a tree structure of the keys so you don't have to compare multiple times.

See [Rabin-Karp Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm)

Do consider existing third party libraries, there must be some.

Comment: he clears Buf at the end of each iteration of the loop (at the bottom)

Comment: I assume `Buf` is a StringBuilder. It's cleared each iteration, so apart from slowing down the program, it does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have 700 pages to test with, but you could try using a regex:

```
var s = Stopwatch.StartNew();
var r = new Regex(string.Join("|", from x in inside select Regex.Escape(x.Key)));

for (int i = 1; i <= a.PageCount; i++)
{
    foreach (Match match in r.Matches(a.Pages[i].Text))
    {
        inside[match.Value].Add(i.ToString());
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(s.Elapsed);
```

Comment: He has many keys to search for. Even for a single, I doubt `regex` can be faster for non-wildcard match but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Standard performance/debugging procedures - comment out pieces of your code and measure. Add them back one at a time until it 'gets bad.' That's likely your problem area.

for example, you might start by commenting out the entire foreach.

It looks like there's some possibly-complex/expensive objects in use - inside, Buf, etc. Comment out the usage of those and put them back one at a time.

Comment: seems unnecessary - with 500 keys and 700 pages, his algorithm is doing 350,000 searches of a page of text for a key. That is likely where the time is being taken.